# Change variable input data size to static in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to use a pretrained Deep Learning model called [deepBlink](https://github.com/BBQuercus/deepBlink/tree/master) to detect peaks in 2D microscopy images in a C++ project. What I originally did was to export the Tensorflow model (`smfish.h5`) in the ONNX format and import it in the C++ project with the OpenCV library (I'm only allowed to use the OpenCV library and not any extra libraries).

I've done this in the past but this time I haven't been able to make a prediction with `model.forward(...)` in C++ because apparently [OpenCV DNN doesn't accept **variable** input data sizes](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19347#issuecomment-1868227401), and that's how the deepBlink architecture is defined:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, None, None, 1)]      0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, None, None, 32)       320       ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 activation (Activation)     (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)       9248      ['dropout[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 activation_1 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d_1[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)       9248      ['dropout_1[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_2 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d_2[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d (  (None, 32)                   0         ['dropout_2[0][0]']           
 GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)               (None, 4)                    132       ['global_average_pooling2d[0][
                                                                    0]']                          
                                                                                                  
 activation_3 (Activation)   (None, 4)                    0         ['dense[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 32)                   160       ['activation_3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 activation_4 (Activation)   (None, 32)                   0         ['dense_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 multiply (Multiply)         (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_4[0][0]',        
                                                                     'dropout_2[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 spatial_dropout2d (Spatial  (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['multiply[0][0]']            
 Dropout2D)                                                                                       
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2  (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['spatial_dropout2d[0][0]']   
 D)                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 64)       18496     ['max_pooling2d[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 activation_5 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_3[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_3 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_5[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 64)       36928     ['dropout_3[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_6 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_4[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_4 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_6[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_5 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 64)       36928     ['dropout_4[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_7 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_5[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_5 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_7[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d_1  (None, 64)                   0         ['dropout_5[0][0]']           
  (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                                                        
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 8)                    520       ['global_average_pooling2d_1[0
                                                                    ][0]']                        
                                                                                                  
 activation_8 (Activation)   (None, 8)                    0         ['dense_2[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 64)                   576       ['activation_8[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 activation_9 (Activation)   (None, 64)                   0         ['dense_3[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 multiply_1 (Multiply)       (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_9[0][0]',        
                                                                     'dropout_5[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 spatial_dropout2d_1 (Spati  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['multiply_1[0][0]']          
 alDropout2D)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPoolin  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['spatial_dropout2d_1[0][0]'] 
 g2D)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)       18464     ['max_pooling2d_1[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 activation_10 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d_6[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_6 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_10[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)       9248      ['dropout_6[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_11 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d_7[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_7 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_11[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)       9248      ['dropout_7[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_12 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d_8[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_8 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_12[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d_2  (None, 32)                   0         ['dropout_8[0][0]']           
  (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                                                        
                                                                                                  
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 4)                    132       ['global_average_pooling2d_2[0
                                                                    ][0]']                        
                                                                                                  
 activation_13 (Activation)  (None, 4)                    0         ['dense_4[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 32)                   160       ['activation_13[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 activation_14 (Activation)  (None, 32)                   0         ['dense_5[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 multiply_2 (Multiply)       multiple                     0         ['activation_14[0][0]',       
                                                                     'dropout_8[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d (UpSampling2  multiple                     0         ['multiply_2[0][0]']          
 D)                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, None, None, 96)       0         ['spatial_dropout2d_1[0][0]', 
                                                                     'up_sampling2d[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 64)       55360     ['concatenate[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 activation_15 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_9[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dropout_9 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_15[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_10 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 64)       36928     ['dropout_9[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_16 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_10[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_10 (Dropout)        (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_16[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_11 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 64)       36928     ['dropout_10[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_17 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_11[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_11 (Dropout)        (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_17[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d_3  (None, 64)                   0         ['dropout_11[0][0]']          
  (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                                                        
                                                                                                  
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 8)                    520       ['global_average_pooling2d_3[0
                                                                    ][0]']                        
                                                                                                  
 activation_18 (Activation)  (None, 8)                    0         ['dense_6[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 64)                   576       ['activation_18[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 activation_19 (Activation)  (None, 64)                   0         ['dense_7[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 multiply_3 (Multiply)       multiple                     0         ['activation_19[0][0]',       
                                                                     'dropout_11[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d_1 (UpSamplin  multiple                     0         ['multiply_3[0][0]']          
 g2D)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_1 (Concatenate  (None, None, None, 96)       0         ['spatial_dropout2d[0][0]',   
 )                                                                   'up_sampling2d_1[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_12 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 32)       27680     ['concatenate_1[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 activation_20 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d_12[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_12 (Dropout)        (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_20[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_13 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 32)       9248      ['dropout_12[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_21 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d_13[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_13 (Dropout)        (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_21[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_14 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 32)       9248      ['dropout_13[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_22 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['conv2d_14[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_14 (Dropout)        (None, None, None, 32)       0         ['activation_22[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d_4  (None, 32)                   0         ['dropout_14[0][0]']          
  (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                                                        
                                                                                                  
 dense_8 (Dense)             (None, 4)                    132       ['global_average_pooling2d_4[0
                                                                    ][0]']                        
                                                                                                  
... 
                                                                                                  
 activation_28 (Activation)  (None, 8)                    0         ['dense_10[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dense_11 (Dense)            (None, 64)                   576       ['activation_28[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 activation_29 (Activation)  (None, 64)                   0         ['dense_11[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 multiply_5 (Multiply)       (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_29[0][0]',       
                                                                     'dropout_17[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 spatial_dropout2d_3 (Spati  multiple                     0         ['multiply_5[0][0]']          
 alDropout2D)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPoolin  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['spatial_dropout2d_3[0][0]'] 
 g2D)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_2 (Concatenate  (None, None, None, 128)      0         ['max_pooling2d_1[0][0]',     
 )                                                                   'max_pooling2d_3[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_18 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 64)       73792     ['concatenate_2[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 activation_30 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_18[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_18 (Dropout)        (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_30[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_19 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 64)       36928     ['dropout_18[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_31 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_19[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_19 (Dropout)        (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_31[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_20 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 64)       36928     ['dropout_19[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_32 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['conv2d_20[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_20 (Dropout)        (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_32[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d_6  (None, 64)                   0         ['dropout_20[0][0]']          
  (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                                                        
                                                                                                  
 dense_12 (Dense)            (None, 8)                    520       ['global_average_pooling2d_6[0
                                                                    ][0]']                        
                                                                                                  
 activation_33 (Activation)  (None, 8)                    0         ['dense_12[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dense_13 (Dense)            (None, 64)                   576       ['activation_33[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 activation_34 (Activation)  (None, 64)                   0         ['dense_13[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 multiply_6 (Multiply)       (None, None, None, 64)       0         ['activation_34[0][0]',       
                                                                     'dropout_20[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_21 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 3)        195       ['multiply_6[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_35 (Activation)  (None, None, None, 3)        0         ['conv2d_21[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 568975 (2.17 MB)
Trainable params: 568975 (2.17 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Therefore, I wanted to ask you how you can change the input size of a Tensorflow model using Python to then export it for this purpose.

What I've tried is the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

model = keras.models.load_model("smfish.h5")

model.layers[0] = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 256, 256, 1), name='input_1')
for layer in connected_layers.keys():
    if len(connected_layers[layer]) == 1:
        layer_to_connect = model.get_layer(connected_layers[layer][0])
        model.get_layer(layer)(layer_to_connect.output)
    elif len(connected_layers[layer]) == 2:
        layer_to_connect_0 = model.get_layer(connected_layers[layer][0])
        layer_to_connect_1 = model.get_layer(connected_layers[layer][1])
        model.get_layer(layer)([layer_to_connect_0.output, layer_to_connect_1.output])
```

where `connected_layers` is the following:

```
connected_layers = {
    'input_1': [],
    'conv2d': ['input_1'],
    'activation': ['conv2d'],
    'dropout': ['activation'],
    'conv2d_1': ['dropout'],
    'activation_1': ['conv2d_1'],
    'dropout_1': ['activation_1'],
    'conv2d_2': ['dropout_1'],
    'activation_2': ['conv2d_2'],
    'dropout_2': ['activation_2'],
    'global_average_pooling2d': ['dropout_2'],
    'dense': ['global_average_pooling2d'],
    'activation_3': ['dense'],
    'dense_1': ['activation_3'],
    'activation_4': ['dense_1'],
    'multiply': ['activation_4', 'dropout_2'],
    'spatial_dropout2d': ['multiply'],
    'max_pooling2d': ['spatial_dropout2d'],
    'conv2d_3': ['max_pooling2d'],
    'activation_5': ['conv2d_3'],
    'dropout_3': ['activation_5'],
    'conv2d_4': ['dropout_3'],
    'activation_6': ['conv2d_4'],
    'dropout_4': ['activation_6'],
    'conv2d_5': ['dropout_4'],
    'activation_7': ['conv2d_5'],
    'dropout_5': ['activation_7'],
    'global_average_pooling2d_1': ['dropout_5'],
    'dense_2': ['global_average_pooling2d_1'],
    'activation_8': ['dense_2'],
    'dense_3': ['activation_8'],
    'activation_9': ['dense_3'],
    'multiply_1': ['activation_9', 'dropout_5'],
    'up_sampling2d': ['multiply_1'],
    'concatenate': ['spatial_dropout2d_1', 'up_sampling2d'],
    'conv2d_9': ['concatenate'],
    'activation_15': ['conv2d_9'],
    'dropout_9': ['activation_15'],
    'conv2d_10': ['dropout_9'],
    'activation_16': ['conv2d_10'],
    'dropout_10': ['activation_16'],
    'conv2d_11': ['dropout_10'],
    'activation_17': ['conv2d_11'],
    'dropout_11': ['activation_17'],
    'global_average_pooling2d_3': ['dropout_11'],
    'dense_6': ['global_average_pooling2d_3'],
    'activation_18': ['dense_6'],
    ...
}
```

describing how the layers are connected.

However, using `model.summary()`, I get the same output as I mentioned above with `None`, so nothing has changed. How can I effectively change the input size?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
cfg = model.get_config()
cfg['layers'][0]['config']['batch_input_shape'] = (1,128,128,3)  # input here the shape you want
new_model = tf.keras.Model.from_config(cfg)
new_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())
```

Dummy example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_ = tf.keras.Input((None, None, 3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, 3, activation='relu')(input_)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,3, activation='relu')(input_)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x,y])
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(input_, x)
model.summary()

cfg = model.get_config()
cfg['layers'][0]['config']['batch_input_shape'] = (1,128,128,3)

new_model = tf.keras.Model.from_config(cfg)
new_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())
new_model.summary()
```

Before:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________  
Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================  
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, None, None, 3)]      0         [] 

 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, None, None, 3)        84        ['input_1[0][0]']
 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 3)        84        ['input_1[0][0]']
 .....
```

After:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(1, 128, 128, 3)]           0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (1, 126, 126, 3)             84        ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (1, 126, 126, 3)             84        ['input_1[0][0]']             
 .....
```